# apps script concatenate with line breaks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a line break with my Google apps script:

`ss.getRange('Y'+lastRow).setFormula('CONCATENATE(F'+lastRow+'&"\n"&G'+lastRow+'&" "&H'+lastRow+')')`

I'm not seeing a line break though. Any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing a line break using the formula you provided. Can you clarify what output you desire, maybe providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Comment: Hi, Did my answer work for you ? Let me know so I can modify it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:%7E:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals,editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification.)

To achieve your goal just put the second line into a new row:

```
   ss.getRange('Y'+lastRow).setFormula
   (
   `CONCATENATE(F${lastRow}&" " 
    &G${lastRow}&" "&H${lastRow})`
   )
```