# Google apps script variable declaration greyed out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script apparently stopped working after google updated. I haven't changed the script.

```
  var newSheet = blankSheet.makeCopy(newEstimate, estimatesFolder);
  var newSheetId = newSheet.getId();
  var newSheetUrl = newSheet.getUrl();
  var newDocUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + copyId + '/edit';
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  var sheetCell = ss.getRange('R'+lastRow).setValue('=HYPERLINK("'+newSheetUrl+'","'+newSheetId+'")');
  var docCell = ss.getRange('S'+lastRow).setValue('=HYPERLINK("'+newDocUrl+'","'+copyId+'")');
```

The `var sheetCell` and the `var docCell` are greyed out but I don't know why?

Comment: do you get any errors? It is not working is not descriptive enough. Also when you concatenate complicated string expressions, it makes sense to use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead.

Comment: When I click the light bulb with the variable highlighted it shows:
Remove declaration for 'sheetCell'
Ignore this error message
Discable checking for this file

Comment: it is a good practice to accept the answer that answers your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64709128/11225291

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64705028/11225291

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64734241/11225291

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:**

Since you haven't indicated any error message, I will shortly explain the greyed out variable declerations.

The decleration for `sheetCell` and `docCell` is **unnecessary** for two reasons:

1. you don't use these variables anywhere in the code after they are declared.
2. while [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) returns a range object, it is not necessary to store it somewhere since its job is to set a value in a cell. In other words, most of the times you don't need the object that it returns.

**Answer:**

Because you declare variables that you **don't use** the new editor gives you an alert message to indicate that the declaration of these variables is **redundant**. This is just a warning message and it is up to you if you want to remove the decleration or not.

[image]